# create new formData using input data less the file type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, user-input

I need to create a formData from the user input (sent from html form) as I need to modify the image picture (compress / resize / crop) and then submit the new FormData to server:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#AddModel").on("submit", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var formData    = new FormData(this);
            var formKeys    = formData.keys();
            var formEntries = formData.entries();

            var processedForm = new FormData();

            // some loop to insert in processedForm all the entries
            // less the file type

            // get the file type (image), process it with canvas and append
            // to the processedForm

            //submit the form

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.prop('action'),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: processedForm,
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data)

            },

        });
    });
```

I know how to modify the image and then append to the `processedForm`but how do I create the `processedForm` taking the user input and appending each input to it but the file? I tried some ifs on formKeys like `if (formKeys != 'image')` to no avail as it seems it doesn't recognize the key (`console.log(formKeys)`)returns only some input not the image.
So how would this loop work?

-- progress so far trying to implement @Kaiido method:

result is: unprocessable entity:`{image: ["The image field is required."]}`

of course I have this in my controller:

```
'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|image|image_size:>=640'
```

I have all this code which is returning a blob with the modified image and teorically appending it to the form, however the controller thinks the image is not there:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#AddModel").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        var inputs = $(this).find('[name]'),

            formData = new FormData();


        inputs.each(function (index, element) {
            if (element.type === 'file') {

                var file = element.files[0];


                if (file.type.match('image.*')) {

                    console.log("it's an image");

                }

                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                reader.onloadend = function () {

                    var base64img = this.result;

                    var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(base64ToArrayBuffer(this.result));
                    var srcOrientation = exif.Orientation;

                    resetOrientationResizeCompress(base64img, srcOrientation).then((img)=> {

                        console.log(img);

                        dataURItoBlob(img).then((ia)=> {

                            console.log(ia);

                            console.log(element.name);

                            formData.append(element.name, ia);

                        });

                    });

                }


            } else {

                formData.append(element.name, element.value);
            }

        });


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.prop('action'),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data)

            }
        });
    });
```

// this function takes care of the original image

```
function resetOrientationResizeCompress(srcBase64, srcOrientation) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {

        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {
            var width = img.width,
                height = img.height,
                canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;

            // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
            if ([5, 6, 7, 8].indexOf(srcOrientation) > -1) {
                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = height;
                canvas.height = width;
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
            }

            // transform context before drawing image
            switch (srcOrientation) {
                case 2:
                    ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, width, height);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, height, 0);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, height, width);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, width);
                    break;
                default:
                    ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            }

            // draw image
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            // export base64
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.6));
        };

        img.src = srcBase64;

    })

};
```

//This one converts base64 to array buffer

```
   function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {

        //base64 = base64.replace(/^data\:([^\;]+)\;base64,/gmi, '');
        base64 = base64.replace(/^data:([^;]+);base64,/gmi, '');
        var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
        var len = binaryString.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes.buffer;
    }
```

//this one converts the dataURItoBlob (probably I can convert directly the canvas.toBlob() but I don't get the callback argument in that method.

```
 function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve) {

            // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
            var byteString;
            if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
                byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
            else
                byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

            // separate out the mime component
            var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

            // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
            var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            resolve(new Blob([ia], {type: mimeString}));

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the original formdata object, and just set a new value for the file input, adding the changed image etc.

You could also use `formData.delete()` to remove the image, and then set the image as a new value

```
$("#AddModel").on("submit", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var image = $('[name=image_input]').get(0).files[0]; // etc

  // change image here

  formData.set('image_input', changed_image_file);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.prop('action'),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {

      console.log(data)

    },

  });
});
```

If browser support is an issue, you can manually iterate over the form inputs and append them to a formData object

```
$("#AddModel").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var inputs   = $(this).find('[name]'),
      formData = new FormData();

  inputs.each(function(index, element) {
      if ( element.type === 'file' ) {
          var file = element.files[0];
          var changed_file = change(file);

          formData.append(element.name, changed_file);

      } else {
          formData.append(element.name, element.value);
      }

  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.prop('action'),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {

      console.log(data)

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: yes you can but delete() and set() have no support in Safari and Opera and almost no support on mobile. It seems append() is the only way so a new FormData must be created from scratch.

Comment: Neither has `formData.entries()` or `keys()` ?

Comment: it seems they have some basic support

Comment: Opera has some basic support, for Safari and IE it's pretty much the same lacking support for all of them

Comment: I'll try the second way with iteration

Comment: @Kaiido - fair enough, all modern browsers should support files now, no need to stringify anything so removed that comment.

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo's answer is right, **when available**, you should use the FormData's methods directly to manipulate it.

But as stated by OP in comments, all browsers don't support all these methods yet...

So one *hackish* workaround, is to remove the `name` attribute of your `<input>` before calling `new FormData(form)`, since only named inputs should be appended to the formData.

*Note : only tested under Safari 9.1.3, I am not sure if all browsers do/did respect this rule...*

```
function noFileFormData(form){
  var files = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');
  var names = [];
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, function(el){
    names.push(el.getAttribute('name')); // save their original names
    el.removeAttribute('name'); // remove their attribute
    }); 
  var formData = new FormData(form); // 'file' input are excluded
  names.forEach(function(n, i){
    if(name){
      files[i].setAttribute('name', n); // restore the attributes
      }
    });
  return formData;
  }
```

From there, you'll be able to append your own Files in the formData, since all implementations do support `.append(name, blob, filename)`.

Comment: I updated the question with the progress I made so far. I can convert the image but then probably append to formData fails as the controller is complaining about the image not being present.

Comment: @Chriz74 Use the filename parameter of of formdata.append(name, blob, filename) That's unfortunately often the first step for file validations, and I guess your controller does use it too.

Comment: I realized I didn't use your way. I'll try tomorrow to check everything

Comment: I used your noFileFormData successfully, I can append the file to the new formData and if I log it I can see it's there. Nonetheless the controller doesn't receive it. Check this other question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269822/image-is-not-posted-to-controller-through-ajax-call-after-formdata-append